# Elasticsearch ORing and ANDing mixed in "must" query

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I want to mixed required values of properties to be ANDed that ORed. After several helpful comments I reworded the question and came up with this:

```
GET /index/docs/_search
{
    "size": 20,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
           "must": [{
               "terms": {
                   "category": ["cat1", "cat2"]
               },
               "terms": {
                   "category": ["cat3"]
               }
           }]
        }
    }
}
```

In the query above (with a "bool" "must" form) does this say that a doc MUST have cat1 AND cat2 OR cat3 in the "category" property?

NOTE: This is significantly modified from the original question.

Comment: The `terms` query is already an OR query. In your example above, you'll get documents whose `category` field contains `cat1` OR `cat2`. Have you tried it out?

Comment: ok, then the opposite becomes the question, how do I AND the categories, requiring all of them. I'll reword the question.

Answer (score 0):

You use to bool query to combine several different types of queries together. You would use it as you did only if you wanted to add another query like a filter or must not etc. along with your terms query. This will still work but it will simply be rewritten into a simpler terms query anyways which will take more time.

The terms query is sufficient for what you want to do and it will return all the documents that contain either cat1 or cat2 in categories.

So your query could just be like :

```
{
    "constant_score" : {
        "filter" : {
            "terms" : { "categories" : ["cat1", "cat2"]}
        }
    }
}
```

You can use this same query inside a must query as well if you want to combine it with some other query.

Take a look at [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) and [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) for reference.

**EDIT**: For the other case ie. and you could use the following query:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "match": { "category": "cat1" }},
        { "match": { "category": "cat2"   }}
    ],
      "minimum_should_match": 2 
    }
  }
```

You can combine all sorts of queries to depending upon what you really want to do. The elasticsearch query DSL documnetation is quite comprehensive in my opinion, you shoukd take a look. Also look at [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bool-query.html), there are many diiferent ways of doing what you want. Keep in mind that term query look for exact matches ie. case sensitive while the match queries rely on analyzed data, so the result can be diffrent in both cases.

Comment: I understand, the question is how to require ORed catagories or ANDed categories. @Val pointed out that the query in the question was ORed so I edited it to ask for ANDed categories meaning that all listed categories must be in the doc.

Comment: I've read much of the docs but would never have though the above was an AND so thankyou. If I understand I could put the 2 terms (they are exact matches and unanalyzed in the application) into a "must" in which case I would not need the `minimum_should_match: 2`? Or is the minimum_should_match what is achieving the AND by forcing a match for each part of the "should"? In other words if I add another category I'd have to make `minimum_should_match: 3`

Comment: If you use "should" then you have to use minimum_should_match: 3 if you wan to use 3 clauses at it basically specifies at least how many of your specified clauses must be in the document. Should is used when you want some kind of partial matching. However, like val said above using must with a bool query will also work and then you wouldn't have to use the minimum_should_match as must means that the document has to contain all the specified clauses. and like I said there are also many other ways of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

According to your latest comment, if you want to AND your categories, the correct way to go is by using `bool/must`, like this:

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      { "match": { "category": "cat1" }},
      { "match": { "category": "cat2"   }}
    ]
  }
}
```

`bool/should` + `minimum_should_match` would work, too, but `bool/must` is more straightforward and doesn't require you to know how many clauses you have.

Comment: If the terms are in a single match (via the array) they are ORed, in separate matches they are ANDed? I had this backwards but thought arrays were treated differently. Will experiment and mark this answered.

Comment: The key here is **must**, i.e. all clauses MUST match (= AND)